# How to change scrollbar thumb color without display permanent?

Tags: html, css

I changed scrollbar thumb color to blue:

[image]

However, the thumb showed all the time.

Anyway can make it show **only scrolling** just like browser do?

Below is my code, you can copy and test:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      div#scrollable {
        border: 5px red solid;
        width: 150px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: blue;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="scrollable">
      <p style="height: 1000px">my text</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change an HTML input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to show the scrollbar whenever you can scroll up or down as per your requirement.

```js
(function(timer) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var el = document.querySelector('.scrollable');
        el.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
            (function(el) {
                el.classList.add('scroll');
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    el.classList.remove('scroll');
                }, 500);
            })(el);
        })
    })
})();
```

```css
.scrollable {
    border: 5px red solid;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

.scrollable.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div id="scrollable" class="scrollable">
        <p style="height: 1000px">my text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollable');
      scrollableDiv.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const thumb = scrollableDiv.querySelector('::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb');
        thumb.style.opacity = '0.6';
        clearTimeout(scrollableDiv.dataset.scrollTimeout);
        scrollableDiv.dataset.scrollTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          thumb.style.opacity = '0';
        }, 1000); // Adjust this timeout to control how long the thumb stays visible after scrolling stops
      });
```

```css
 div#scrollable {
        border: 5px red solid;
        width: 150px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y: auto;
```

```html
    <!-- SimpleBar CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar/dist/simplebar.min.css" />

  <body>
    <div id="scrollable" data-simplebar>
      <p style="height: 1000px">my text</p>
    </div>

    <!-- SimpleBar JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar/dist/simplebar.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

may these changes help!

```
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            display: none;
        }

        div#scrollable:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            display: block;
            background: blue;
        }
```